# Encoding '_sbcs' has incorrect 'chars' (must be of len 128 or 256) when using node-mssql

Tags: sql-server, encoding, node-sqlserver

I am using node-mysql to return a simply dataset,  my db table only have 2 varchar fields,  when I started my application to querying the data, it throws error 'Encoding '_sbcs' has incorrect 'chars' (must be of len 128 or 256) '

the versions are 
  * NodeJS:  10.15.3
  * node-mssql: 4.3.5
  * SQL Server: ms SQL 2014

> Error: Encoding '_sbcs' has incorrect 'chars' (must be of len 128 or
>   256)
>       at new SBCSCodec (C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\sbcs-codec.js:14:15)
>       at Object.getCodec (C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js:100:25)
>       at Object.getDecoder (C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js:127:23)
>       at Object.decode (C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js:40:25)
>       at C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\tedious\lib\value-parser.js:379:22
>       at C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:433:9
>       at Parser.awaitData (C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:144:9)
>       at Parser.readBuffer (C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:430:12)
>       at readChars (C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\tedious\lib\value-parser.js:378:19)
>       at C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\tedious\lib\value-parser.js:188:20
>       at C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:203:9
>       at Parser.awaitData (C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:144:9)
>       at Parser.readUInt16LE (C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:200:12)
>       at readDataLength (C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\tedious\lib\value-parser.js:67:27)
>       at C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\tedious\lib\value-parser.js:89:5
>       at readTextPointerNull (C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\tedious\lib\value-parser.js:36:5)
>       at valueParse (C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\tedious\lib\value-parser.js:88:3)
>       at next (C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\nbcrow-token-parser.js:34:45)
>       at C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\nbcrow-token-parser.js:53:5
>       at C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:433:9
>       at Parser.awaitData (C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:144:9)
>       at Parser.readBuffer (C:\Users\qpan\Downloads\bzwapp-1.2.0+0272\bzwapps\lib\auth\mssql-auth\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:430:12)

Comment: https://github.com/NielsLeenheer/EscPosEncoder/issues/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, my issue is caused by 'ANT', the deploy tool,
I used ANT to copy the folder and files in 'node-model' , but the encoding of file 'sbcs-data-generated.js' was changed from UTF-8 to ANSI. that caused the problem.

my solution was ---   added 'encoding="UTF-8"'  in build.xml